# Persistence of variables in a service using Perspective Broker in Python Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm having a problem using the Perspective Broker feature of Twisted Python. The structure of my code is like this:

```
class DBService(service.Service):
    def databaseOperation(self, input):
        # insert input into DB

class PerspectiveRoot(pb.Root):
    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service

    def remote_databaseOperation(self, input):
        return self.service.databaseOperation(input)

db_service = DBService()
pb_factory = pb.PBServerFactory(PerspectiveRoot(db_service))
```

I hook up the factory to a TCP server and then multiple clients connect, who are able to insert records into the database via the `remote_databaseOperation` function.

This works fine until the number of requests gets big, then I end up with duplicate inputs and missing inputs. I assume this is because DBService's 'input' variable persists and gets overwritten during simultaneous requests. Is this correct? And, if so, what's the best way to rewrite my code so it can deal with simultaneous requests?

My first thought is to have DBService maintain a list of DB additions and loop through it, while clients are able to append to the list. Is this the most 'Twisted' way to do it?

Alternatively, is there a separate pb.Root instance for every client? In which case, I could move the database operation into there since its variables won't get overwritten.

Comment: As you've written it here, there is no way for databaseOperation's `input` to persist or be accessed simultaneously from multiple requests. The code you've elided with the "insert input into DB" comment may be relevant. Are you using adbapi? adbapi2? alchimia? txpostgres?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not enough information here to determine what might be going wrong.  As it stands you've only shown the most basic possible use of PB; please see http://sscce.org for more information about constructing a useful example.